# My C program doesn't show any error but after that it does not run

Tags: c

Here's the program it doesn't show any error on pressing ctrl+f9.
it says press any key to continue and i do it and then it doesn't run
i use turbo c++ 4.0 and i have saved the file in .c format
Please suggest the changes i should do to execute my program.

Thanks

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>

float main()
    {
    float l,b,r;
    float circ,area,arsq,peri;
    clrscr ();
    printf ("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
    scanf ("%f", l);
    printf ("\nEnter the breadth of the rectangle: ");
    scanf ("%f", b);
    printf ("\nEnter the radius of the circle: ");
    scanf ("%f", r);
    peri = l+b+l+b;
    area = 3.14*r*r;
    arsq = l*b;
    circ = 3.14*2*r;

    printf ("\n\nThe perimeter of the rectangle is: %f",peri);
    printf ("\n\nThe area of the rectangle is: %f",arsq);
    printf ("\n\nThe circumfrence of the circle is: %f",circ);
    printf ("\n\nThe area of the circle is: %f",area);
    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the source of your problem, but main() should not be declared to return a float.  It should be:  int main(int argc, char ** argv).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner this is definitely not the sourece of his problems, see answer below.

Comment: Try to use Alt+F9 (Compile) before to use Ctrl+F9.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner i had forgotten to use &l instead of l.

Comment: @SnehilGupta It's true, the error is caused by missing &. But the remark of Jeremy still right, main can't have only one form : int main(int argc, char * argv[])

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
scanf ("%f", l);
scanf ("%f", b);
scanf ("%f", r);
```

To

```
scanf ("%f", &l);
scanf ("%f", &b);
scanf ("%f", &r);
```

As `%f` in those `scanf`s expects the address of the variable(`float*`) instead of its value.

Also, `main` should return an `int`, not a `float`, as per the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int main()`. C standard requires return type of int:

> (5.1.2.2.1) It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters ... or with two parameters ... or in some other implementation-defined manner

Answer (score 0):

main function should return int otherwise you will get unexpected behavior and I think this is one of the side effects.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using turbo C++, you should use **void main()** and no **return** statement in your program.
Also, **scanf("%f", l)** is not correct, it doesnt show an error in turbo c++ but you need to pass the address of variable as second arguement to scanf() function like **scanf("%f", &l)**.

Comment: bro the program isn't running without the return statment

Comment: if that's the case, then use int main() and return 0, it would work!!